# how to implement automatic functional tests in php

Tags: php, testing, phpunit

Everywhere I read about the importance of automated tests. I understand the importance and I will do it in my upcoming projects now (a little bit late I know but better late than never ;-))

I read many things about unit tests and I know tools that I can use (PHPUnit is the preferred tool of nearly everyone). But how about functional tests? I read some specialist literature about functional tests but I could not found a detailed description how to implement such tests und which tools I can use.
What is the exact difference?

I spent some time to google that, so I would be glad if someone could give me a link to a documentation or a recommendation for a book of this topic.

Every hint is very appreciated ;-)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Functional tests are built on use scenarii. There are basicaly two approaches to adress this:

1. You start from the use-cases document and you define your target devices. then for each case/device, you write a script with whatever is adapted to your environment (for web, Selenium is a very good choice)
2. When you have an existing site or product: you capture your traffic and replay real sequences of use that will validate non regression (from a functional point of view). This is a bit tricky, but very powerful.

Please note that both approaches are not incompable, but rather complement each others.

What do you want to test and what do you start with?

Answer (score 0):

It depends of what you want to test and who is writing this test. If the business people want to write some functional tests, you should have an ATDD approach with tools like Behat and Selenium.

If you (the developer I guess) want to write functional tests, what do you want to test ? Do you want to check things like

```
if I put 'myName' in the input 'name' and I click on the 'submit' button, 
I will be redirected to a page with 'myName' in a 'h1'
```

or more :

```
if I send array('name' => 'myName') to MyController, 
a new user will be created in the database and i will be redirected to this user page
```

For the first approach, you should use again a tool like Selenium wich could simulate all users action. It's a very powerful and popular tool. I think (but it's just an opinion) that this approach has a too big granularity with the UI and it's just good for non-regression tests and not for TDD.

My approach is to write high level tests with PHPUnit. This tests call directly your routes or the controllers and check that all the business rules are respected. With this tests, I can parse the DOM to check if the good informations are in the page (with the [symfony crawler](http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/dom_crawler.html) for exemple). This tests are fast to write and integrated in your PHPUnit workflow so it's easy to start with. I don't know if we can call it "functional tests" but they do this role in my projects.

But writing this kind of tests depends a lot of your framework. I use Laravel 4 wich is designed to be testable so it's really simple but in a previous experience (with FuelPHP) it was impossible.

I hope it can help you to forge your own opinion.